# Like which browser does tidesdk read the code like

Tags: html, css, browser, tidesdk

I want to run a twitter bootstrap code on tidesdk, does the web page display work like internet explorer, where bootstrap is not fully supported?

In other words what browser would tidesdk interpret the code most likely as. This is for making html and css code to look exactly like I want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will render similar to Google Chrome as it is a WebKit browser.

See: http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/guide/getting_started

> in conjunction with a WebKit client and a familiar and extensive API

Answer (score 1):

TideSDK uses WebKit as underlying technology. You may find some difficulties as the webkit used is quite old. [TideKit](http://tidekit.com) is the new technology and the future path for TideSDK users. here is the blog post about the comparison how TideKit would be better than TideSDK https://blog.tidekit.com/post/from-a-desktop-perspective-tidekit-for-tidesdk-developers

Comment: Thank you, I just got around to implementing some code on tidesdk , I think the concept is amazing, but using Jquery and the fluidity of things is a bit rough, its good to hear about the improvements comming!